# Using SDL2 on linux with g++?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, sdl, sdl-2

```
   #include "SDL2/SDL.h"


   int main(int argc, char* args[])
   {
       SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

       SDL_QUIT();
       return 0;
  }
```

I have installed SDL2 through the debian repositories, and I am running

```
g++ -o test.cpp a.out -lSDL2
```

I get a whole lot of errors:

```
a.out:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
a.out: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
a.out: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
a.out: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
a.out: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
a.out: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
a.out:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in a.out(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried

```
g++ test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2)
```

and get:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:6:14: error: ‘(SDL_EventType)256u’ cannot be used as a function
```

I have no idea what is causing these errors. 
The proper header files are present in the

/usr/include/SDL2/

directory. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The header must be: `<SDL2/SDL.h>` 
The quit function:  `SDL_Quit();` 
The command:        `g++ teste.cpp -o filename -lSDL2`

Comment: I don't like adding SDL2/ in front of header filenames in source. It reduces portability if SDL2 is installed somewhere else. Also, we don't need it on Windows. I prefer to indicate it in g++ command line flag like -I/usr/include/SDL2.

Answer (score 4):

// Bad:`g++ -o test.cpp a.out -lSDL2`

// Good: `g++ test.cpp -lSDL2` (a.out implicit)

// Better: `g++ test.cpp -g -pedantic -o test -lSDL2`

I suspect the main problem might simply have been putting the g++ arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: 'g++ test.cpp -G -pedantic -o test -lSDL2' 
The "-G" command is unrecognized

Comment: Hi - my bad.  Sorry.  Lower-case "-g": `g++ -g -Wall -pedantic test.cpp -o test -lSDL2`

Answer (score 1):

like Tietbohl said

SDL_QUIT is part of the enum  SDL_EventType
http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventType

you should use SDL_Quit();
http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Quit